# What are best known algorithms/techniques for updating edges on huge graph structures like social networks?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph

On social networks like twitter where millions follow single account, it must be very challenging to update all followers instantly when a new tweet is posted. Similarly on facebook there are fan pages with millions of followers and we see updates from them instantly when posted on page. I am wondering what are best known techniques and algorithms to achieve this. I understand with billion accounts, they have huge data centers across globe and even if we reduce this problem for just one computer in following manner - 100,000 nodes with average 200 edges per node, then every single node update will require 200 edge updates. So what are best techniques/algorithms to optimize such large updates. Thanks!

Comment: They likely don't store it in a huge graph. Instead they probably maintain various database tables. And when you open your page, it will query all posts you are subscribed to etc. If you subscribe to a new channel, they only need to update an entry in the table and thats it, more or less.

Comment: For StackOverflow, your question is too broad, unfortunately. Please check [ask], thanks.

Comment: Also note that a graph with 100k nodes is not that huge. I worked a lot with street networks and similar stuff. My usual road or transit graphs had more than 10mio nodes. And its still quite easy to operate on those graphs using standard algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is usually just to do all the updates.  You say they can be seen "instantly", but actually the updates probably propagate through the network and can take up to a few seconds to show up in followers' feeds.

Having to do all those updates may seem like a lot, but on average follower will check for updates much more often than a person being followed will produce them, and checking for updates has to be much faster.

The choices are:

1. Update 1 million followers, a couple times a day, within a few seconds; or
2. Respond to checks from 1 million followers, a couple *hundred* times a day, within 1/10 second or so.

There are in-between strategies involving clustering users and stuff, but usage patterns like you see on Facebook and Twitter are probably so heavily biased toward option (1) that such strategies don't pay off.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I believe they may be using clustering to optimize operations. Can you recommend any research paper on the subject?